# program that takes a number from the user and verifies that it's between 7 and 11?

Tags: java

I'm not really familiar with Java... i have an assignment where i need to make a program that takes a number from the user and verifies that it's between 7 and 11 inclusive. I have tried to do it but im stuck. This is what iv'e tried to do so far.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class assignment8 {


    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args){ 

       int value1 = 7;
       int value2 = 11;

        if(value1 == value2)
            System.out.println("value1 == value2");
        if(value1 != value2)
            System.out.println("value1 != value2");
        if(value1 > value2)
            System.out.println("value1 > value2");
        if(value1 < value2)
            System.out.println("value1 < value2");
        if(value1 <= value2)
            System.out.println("value1 <= value2");

        System.out.print("Please enter a number ");

    }
}
```

Comment: The way you have your expressions written, only two of them will be true.  You should get the input *first*, then check against either value1 or value2.  Hint:  there's no sense in checking one of your values if the other isn't satisfied.

Comment: You are missing an important part: reading a number from the user. This number than needs to be compared to the interval.

Comment: Do you know any programming? What would you do to check that the "input" number is in the range 7-11? Let's say using just simple AND and OR statements?

Comment: yeah i really dont know anything to be honest. im really really rudimentary at this point

Comment: Well, it seems to me that you want your program to do four different things.  (1) Print a message that asks the user for a number.  (2) Read the number from the keyboard.  (3) Check whether the number is in the required range.  (4) Print a message that shows the result of the check.  You're doing three of those four things already, but you need to make sure that your program does them in the right order.  So think carefully about what the order should be, and re-arrange some of the things that your program does.  As far as the steps that you've missed, or that you're not doing correctly, ...

Comment: ... you could get the information that you need from one of the answers that have been provided for you.

Comment: @alostperson it might be best for you to learn the basics first, watch java/C videos here : https://buckysroom.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing to take the input from the user.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Please enter a number");
int num = scan.nextInt(); // take the input from the user.

if(num >= 7 && num <=11){ //case to make sure that the number lies between 7 and 11 inclusively
    System.out.print("The number "+num+" lies between 7 and 11");
}
else{
    System.out.println("The number "+num+" does not lie between 7 and 11");
}
```

Comment: Don't know if you are actually helping the op with this posting!

Comment: Just answering the question because I <3 Java!

Comment: What about if i wanted to make a program that takes a number from the user and verifies that it's less than 52 or greater than 102?

Comment: Please try that by yourself since this solution is very similar to what you want next.

Comment: The one additional piece of information that you need is that `||` means "OR".

Answer (score 2):

```
public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Enter number here : ");
        int num;

        Scanner scanIn = new Scanner(System.in);

        try {

            num = scanIn.nextInt();

            if (num >= 7 && num <= 11) {
                System.out.println("Number is between 7 and 11 inclusive");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Number is not between 7 and 11");
            }
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("Please enter a valid integer");
        } finally {
            scanIn.close();
        }`enter code here`

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to first take the input and validate against the input using conditions see my sample code here :)
Learn the [basics from here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/index.html)

```
public class SeventoElevenInclusive {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a number");
        int number=input.nextInt();

        if(number>=7 && number<=11){
            System.out.println(number+" is accepted");
        }
        else if(number<7){
                System.out.println(number+" is less than 7");
            }
        else{
            System.out.println(number+" is greater than 11");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: This is poorly indented and hard to read; and it's poor form to omit braces following an `if`.  These are small things but it's worth getting them right if you're setting out to teach someone something.

Comment: @DavidWallace I improved formatting and indentation thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything where you read in a number. Your `Scanner` field isn't `static` so `main()` couldn't use it. I do approve of storing your min and max constants but I don't personally care for their current names (`value1` and `value2`). Instead, I think you wanted something like -

```
private static final int MIN = 7;
private static final int MAX = 11;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter a number ");
    if (in.hasNextInt()) {
        int num = in.nextInt();
        if (num < MIN) {
            System.err.printf("%d is less than the minimum of %d%n", num,
                    MIN);
        } else if (num > MAX) {
            System.err.printf("%d is greater than the maximum of %d%n",
                    num, MAX);
        } else {
            System.out.printf("%d is between %d and %d%n", num, MIN, MAX);
        }
    }
}
```